# Array splitting seems not to be working , and also Maps and Lists refused to be populated

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, maps

Can someone please show me what is wrong with this block of code.

What I am trying to do is to create a phone-book that will receive the first input as the amount of entries the user want to enter, and the subsequent inputs will be the input of the phonebook details in 
the form of a long string.

It will include the name of the person and the phone number, in a single line and then after the input, I will split the inputted values into two and store each as a key and value in a map.

But my code is not working.

What am I doing with the Lists is this:

The input from stdin will be a single string of the name and the phone number in a single line of input. So what I am trying to do is to split the long string of name and number into two(name and number), and store them both in a list, then when I want to populate the Map I will then call the index of the list where the number is situated and use it as the value, and also call the index of the list where the name is situated and use it as key in the Map.

I have tried using an array but there are problems when splitting the string. With this list now the splitted strings seems not to be saving in the list, probably because of iterations of the loops.

An insight will be helpful

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testube {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int phoneBookSize = sc.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[phoneBookSize];
        String[] numbers = new String[phoneBookSize];
        Map<String, String> phoneBook = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String[] inputNameAndNumber = new String[2];
        String name;
        String number;
        List<String> keepStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneBookSize; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                inputNameAndNumber = sc.next().split(" ");

                String holder = inputNameAndNumber[j];
                keepStrings.add(holder);
                // name = inputNameAndNumber[0];
                // number = inputNameAndNumber [1];

            }
            phoneBook.put(keepStrings.get(0), keepStrings.get(1));


        }
        System.out.println(phoneBook.entrySet());
    }
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Please add some space in you explain  fomat well

Comment: `phoneBook.put(keepStrings.get(0), keepStrings.get(1));` <- because you are not clearing the keepStrings list inside you loops this will allways add the same key/value. So you should end up with only 1 entry

Comment: the input will be a space seperated single long string which will consist of the name and number , i.e sam 08129014778. the input will have to on untill the first For_Loop is satisfied; this means the user will enter more than  one names and phone numbers, but each input will consists of the name and number , which the inner loop is meant to split into two and store in an array , and then stored in a list to be used to populate the map.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS  i do not understand what you mean by clearing the keepString List; please  explain further....

Comment: The list "keepStrings" needs to be re-instantiated or cleared otherwise the objects would keep piling up in other indexes. The list will maintain its state (+ more objects further down the index) i.e. the objects on the index 0 and 1 will be the same until cleared or re-instantiated.

Comment: @OlalekanAdebari: You declare your list outside the loop and then fill it inside. On the first iteration you will insert 2 values at index 0 and 1. But because you do not clear the list (aka delete the previous entries) when it reaches the line `keepStrings.add(holder);` when the outer for loop runs a second time it will insert the next strings into the already existing list at index 2 and 3. You either need to call the clear method of the list or move the creation  `List<String> keepStrings = new ArrayList<String>();` inside your loop so that you will get a new list every time the loop runs

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS ok

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your `j`loop. It let you input your name and number twice to work correctly because of `sc.next()` is inside this loop.

The 2nd point is that your phonebook will only contains one entry because you always putting the same values. This is because your list is never cleared.

You may change your loop to:

```
// consume 'new line' after sc.nextInt()
sc.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < phoneBookSize; i++) {
    // note: change `next` to `nextLine`
    inputNameAndNumber = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    name = inputNameAndNumber[0];
    number = inputNameAndNumber[1];
    phoneBook.put(name, number);
}
```

So in each iteration to populate your phonebook you're changing `name` and `number` by the next input.

Your input holds both name and number in one line like

```
Alex 123
Ben 456
Ed 789
```

Comment: you can see in the code that i commented out the variables: "name and number", when i tried doing it this way , the array inputNameAndNumber returned indexOutOFbound error, which i dont know why, because the capacity of the arrayis 2, and the values to be stored in it is also 2, that is why i changed it to use ArrayList.

Comment: You declare and initialise `inputNameAndNumber` with size = 2. But this is not necessary because you re-assign a new instance to this variable using `split`. So if there is an exception you should debug your code and have a look into this variable after splitting the input.

Comment: `String#split` does not consume white spaces so at first you need to consume the 'new line' after `nextInt` and to input your values you need to use `sc.nextLine()`

Comment: you said i should remove the J For_Loop; when i remove it , it return ArrayIndexOutOfBound Error, at the second assighnment of the array value; that is when i do : name= inputNameAndNumber[1]; i dont know why, because i moved the initialization of :String [] InputNameAndNumber = sc.nextInt().split(" "); into the loop.

Comment: Save `sc.next()` into a variable and print it and you'll see the problem. Maybe I didn't get it correctly then please add your input to the question

Answer (score 0):

The list `keepStrings` needs to be re-instantiated or cleared otherwise the objects would keep piling up in other indexes. The list will maintain its state (+ more objects further down the index) i.e. the objects on the index 0 and 1 will be the same until cleared or re-instantiated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneBookSize; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                inputNameAndNumber = sc.next().split(" ");

                String holder = inputNameAndNumber[j];
                keepStrings.add(holder);
                // name = inputNameAndNumber[0];
                // number = inputNameAndNumber [1];

            }
            phoneBook.put(keepStrings.get(0), keepStrings.get(1));

            keepStrings.clear();

        }
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneBookSize; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                    keepStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
                    inputNameAndNumber = sc.next().split(" ");

                    String holder = inputNameAndNumber[j];
                    keepStrings.add(holder);
                    // name = inputNameAndNumber[0];
                    // number = inputNameAndNumber [1];

                }
                phoneBook.put(keepStrings.get(0), keepStrings.get(1));

            }
```

Though the first solution serves here better.